# How to re-order an array of objects based on a list of ids

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

I have an object Task as you can see below:

```
class Task
  include HTTParty

  attr_accessor :id, :name, :assignee_status, :order

  def initialize(id, name, assignee_status)
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.status = status
    self.order = order
 end
end
```

So, when I load a list of tasks, I give them a specific order, like this:

```
i = 0
@tasks.each do |at|
    at.order = i
    i += 100
end
```

This list is, then, sent over json to a client app which shows is to the user and allows for drag'n'drop. After some task is re-ordered, the front-end app sends a list back to the server with all the task ids in the new order.

Example: 
23,45,74,22,11,98,23

What I want to do is the re-order the array of objects based on the ids that I found. What I thought about doing was to set all order to 0 and then search each object individually on the matrix and set their priority accordingly. But this just feels wrong... feels to computing intensive.

Is there a clever way to do something like:

ArrayOfTaskObjects.orderbyAttribute(id) ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easy way is to iterate the params with a index, something like:

```
params['task_ids'].split(",").each_with_index do |task_id, idx|
  task = lookup_the_task_based_on_id
  task.order = idx
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_by_id(array)

  r = array.inject({}) { |hash, element| hash.merge!(element.id => element) }
  temp_array = r.sort_by {|k,_| k}
  temp_array.flatten!.grep(temp_array.last.class)

end
```

What's happening:

The `sort_by_id` method takes in an array of objects - this being your Task array.

In the first line of code a hash is created which stores each Task id as the key and the Task object as the value.

The second line of code sorts the hash based on the keys (note that the r.sort_by method returns a two dimensional array, ex. `[[23, Task], [44, Task], [54, Task]]`).

And finally the third line of code flattens your two dimensional array into a one dimensional array and greps removes all id's from the two dimensional array leaving the array of Tasks in order.